# How do I specify both objects when overriding equals method?

Tags: java, android, overriding, equals

I'm doing an assignment that asks me to override the equals method of a house class.

The instructions are as follows:

> Two houses are equal when their building areas are equal and their pool status is the same

Until now, this is what I've wrote:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
   if (other instanceof House) {
         House otherHouse = (House) other;
         return otherHouse.calcBuildingArea() == ???   
             && otherHouse.mPool == ???
   } else {
         return false;
   }
}
```

Now I don't know what to write after the `==` signs. I don't know how to specify the object that calls the method.

Comment: You can use the "this" keyword to reference the current object.

Comment: Can you please show me how you would write that line? I'm a bit new to this...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a method without specifying an object, the method will get called on the current object.  So you can write

```
return otherHouse.calcBuildingArea() == calcBuildingArea()
         && otherHouse.mPool == mPool;
```

or if you want to make it nice and clear and explicit, you can write

```
return otherHouse.calcBuildingArea() == this.calcBuildingArea()
         && otherHouse.mPool == this.mPool;
```

Note also that this assumes that `mPool` is of a primitive type or an `enum` type.  If it's a reference type, such as `String`, you may need to invoke its `equals` method like

```
return otherHouse.calcBuildingArea() == calcBuildingArea()
         && otherHouse.mPool.equals(mPool);
```

or even the more null-friendly

```
return otherHouse.calcBuildingArea() == calcBuildingArea()
         && Objects.equals(otherHouse.mPool, mPool);
```

Comment: Wow; amazing answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
return otherHouse.calcBuildingArea() == this.calcBuildingArea()   
         && otherHouse.mPool == this.mPool
```

Comment: You should check that `otherHouse` is actually a `House`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils The code to do that particular check is already in the question.  OP only wanted to know what to write on the line with the `???` marks in the question.  This answer is correct.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils i was just answering Pshemo's specific question about what should be in the places of ???. this code is already inside the if block to assure other is a House.

Comment: I didn't say it was incorrect @DavidWallace; I suggested something. When someone asks such a basic question, maybe it's appropriate to suggest alternatives to what they've come up with.